# saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[String] spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some spark code that joins two Arryas into one and then does some formating like this:

```
    def formatMap3(sep: String = "",
    left: String = "", right: String = "")(m: Map[String, String]) = {
  val items = m.toSeq.map{case (k, v) => {
   s"$k$sep $v"}}
  s"$left$items$right"
}


def formatMap3(m: String = "") = {
  val items = m.map{case (k) => {
   s"$k"}}
  s"$items"
}



val combPrdGrp = custPrdGrp3.join(cmpgnPrdGrp3)

val combPrdGrp2 = combPrdGrp.groupByKey


val combPrdGrp3 = combPrdGrp2.map{case (k3, vals3) => {
  val valsString3 = vals3.map{case (id3, m3) => 
     s"$id3 $m3"
   }
   s"$k3 $valsString3"
 }}
```

when I try to print the results like below, I get the following error:

```
scala> combPrdGrp3.collect.saveAsTextFile(file1)
<console>:60: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[String]
              combPrdGrp3.collect.saveAsTextFile(file1)
```

I get results on the screen with just `combPrdGrp3.collect`, but why doens't `saveAsTextFile` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveAsTextFile` is a method for RDDs in spark.  If you call `collect` on an RDD, it goes out to the nodes and collects the data from the RDD returning the actual object that the RDD represents.  If you remove the `collect`, the `saveAsTextFile` should work as expected.